# TypeError: Cannot read property 'status' of undefined when receiving errors from Laravel validation

Tags: laravel, vue.js, axios

I'm trying to validate a form via AJAX using Axios with vue.

```
axios.post('api/registro', this.sede)
.then(response => {

    this.$emit('cerrar')

})
.catch(err => {

    console.log(err)

})
```

The error comes from the catch part, as it's coming from a Laravel validator. The response from the server is 422 and it contains a JSON with a message and the errors the server is sending.

Everything works fine if I dont try to log the error.

Comment: Where are you reading the `status` property?

Answer (score 2):

The problem was coming from me using interceptors in axios, I wasn't returning the errors in the interceptors properly, so nothing was coming into the catch function.

This is what I had:

```
axios.interceptors.response.use(null, function (error) {
    // some logic
  });
```

And this is how it should've been:

```
axios.interceptors.response.use(null, function (error) {
    // some logic
    return Promise.reject(error);
  });
```

Thank you all so much for your help.

Answer (score 1):

You can just check for errors like so:

```
if(err.response.data.errors){
  this.errors = err.response.data.errors;
}
```

`this.errors` would be an array you can loop through using `v-for` to display it